# How to connect CakePHP 3.4 with remote SQL database

Tags: sql, database, cakephp, azure-sql-database, database-connection

I need to connect the CakePHP 3.4 application with the SQL database. Already application has a connection with MySQL database, but need to connect to this SQL database for other purposes.

Comment: You just add a second connection definition in your configuration. What have you tried, and what isn't working about it?

Comment: I have tried to connect with sqlsrv_connect, but it is not working because my server does not have that driver. The support team unable to install the same. And mainly I didn't use cake datasource

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple no extra configuration.
But check that hosting/MySQL provider allows wildcard entry. mean host other than the server can connect to your MySQL, so confirm that wildcard/prefer domain is enabled.

in your **config.php**

```
    'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => Connection::class,
            'driver' => Mysql::class,
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'yourhost.com',
            'username' => 'username_of_host',
            'password' => 'password_of_host',
            'database' => '**************',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'flags' => [],
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'log' => false,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
.......................
]
        ],
```

Comment: How to make this connection only for a particular controller function.